# Eclipse Che Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: eclipse, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, eclipse-che

Having challenges running Eclipse Che multiuser mode on Google Cloud computer engine instance.

Environment
(che cli): 6.1.0 - using docker 17.03.2-ce / native

Input:

```
docker run -it -e CHE_MULTIUSER=true -e CHE_HOST={server-ip} -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/d
ocker.sock -v {localuserfolder}:/data eclipse/che start
```

Output:

```
INFO: (che start):  Starting containers...
docker_compose --file="/data/instance/docker-compose-container.yml" -p="che" up -d >> "/data/cli.log" 2>&1
che_postgres_1 is up-to-date

ERROR: for che  Container "4a245b40b556" is unhealthy.
ERROR: for keycloak  Container "4a245b40b556" is unhealthy.
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
ERROR: Error during 'compose up' - printing 30 line tail of {localuserfolder}/cli.log:
```

Noticed issue has something do to with postgres not having permission to run some scripts:

```
docker container logs che_postgres_1
/usr/bin/container-entrypoint: line 3: exec: /var/lib/pgsql/init-che-user-and-run.sh: cannot execute: Permission denied
/usr/bin/container-entrypoint: line 3: /var/lib/pgsql/init-che-user-and-run.sh: Permission denied
```

Documented [fix](https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/7194) doesn't work, `:/data` is already mounted to read/writable directory.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Google Cloud overrides file system permissions somehow. Have you tried mounting different dirs into `:/data`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your command and it works in my case by using a GCP instance with Debian 9 and docker 17.12, here is the steps that I've followed:

1) install docker

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common


$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg | sudo apt-key add -


$ sudo add-apt-repository    "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

2) run che, I've used as a directory the /tmp, I recommend you to create another directory to store the files

```
$ sudo docker run -it -e CHE_MULTIUSER=true -e CHE_HOST=INTERNAL-IP -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /DIRECTORY_WITH_PERMISSIONS:/data eclipse/che start
```

Comment: Let me try, I used the GCE container template. I believe that deploys to coreOS